# Django - ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: django, oracle

I have a table in my Oracle database that one of her columns is a `NUMBER(38,0)`.

If I directly do an insert in the database with a number like "6688930737147338195" , the insert goes OK.

But, when I use django `object.save()` with the number it gives me this error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

I ran this code in my oracle database to try fix this:

```
ALTER TABLE XYZ MODIFY Z NUMBER(38,0); COMMIT;
```

But the problem in Django still occurs. It gives the same error. *But*, for some reason, the object it's saved in the database even after this error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

This happened because I was using `django-simple-history` plugin in my project.
This plugin records the modifications in a specified model in your `models.py` using the line below your model specification:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=true)
    #This line below
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

So, in the model that I was having this problem had this plugin enabled for him. If I update an AutoField to BigAutoField the HistoricalRecords table of this models isn't updated when I execute the django `makemigrations`.

**The solution was**:
Comment the HistoricalRecords() line ---> makemigrations, migrate ---> Uncomment the HistoricalRecords() --> makemigrations, migrate again